# how to test if form is post or get?

Tags: php, symfony1

how will i do this? i have the code:

```
 public function executeListmatches(sfWebRequest $request)
{
    $form_values = $request->getParameter('match_form', array());   
    if (isset($HTTP_POST_VARS))
    {
        $gender_id = $form_values['gender_id2'];
        $age1 = $form_values['age1'];
        $age2 = $form_values['age2'];
        $province_id = $form_values['id'];
    }
    else
    {
        echo $gender_id =  $request->getParameter('gender2');
        echo $age1 =  $request->getParameter('age1');
        echo $age2 =  $request->getParameter('age2');
        echo $province_id =  $request->getParameter('id');
    }
    $this->pager = $this->setupPager($gender_id,$age1,$age2,$province_id);  
    return sfView::SUCCESS;
}
```

but the line  if (isset($HTTP_POST_VARS)) is not correct
thank you

Comment: Note that `$HTTP_POST_VARS` is deprecated now and you should use `$_POST` (although this isn't the solution to your problem)

Comment: Why would you do this? Seems like a security issue to me. You should always know if a form is post or get. Not knowing indicates that you don't know where the input is coming from. If you are accepting 3rd party submissions you should establish rules for those submissions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check the method with `sfWebRequest::isMethod($name);`.

So use: `if ($request->isMethod('POST'))`.

Answer (score 1):

HTTP_POST_VARS & HTTP_GET_VARS are both deprecated. Your first condition is usisng POST data